# break line regex

Tags: swift, regex, string

How can I match a break line from OCR text using regex?
For example I have this text:

> "NAME 
>    JESUS
>   LASTNAME"

I want to find a match with NAME and then get the next two lines

```
if (line.text.range(of: "^NAME+\\n", options: .regularExpression) != nil){
    let name = line.text
    print(name)
}
```

Comment: The "pure regex" approach would be to have your regex written to match 3 consecutive lines, capturing the latter 2 as capture groups. However, a mixed-approach might be simpler, where you find the indices of the `NAME` keyword, then use `takeWhile` to grab the substrings up the the following new line characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a positive look behind to find NAME followed by a new line, and try to match a line followed by any text that ends on a new line or the end of a string `"(?s)(?<=NAME\n).*\n.*(?=$|\n)"`:

For more info about the regex above you can check [this](https://regex101.com/r/UDael6/1)

Playground testing:

---

```
let str = "NAME\nJESUS\nLASTNAME"

let pattern = "(?s)(?<=NAME\n).*\n.*(?=$|\n)"
if let range = str.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) {
    let text = String(str[range])
    print(text)
}
```

---

This will print

> JESUS
> LASTNAME

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```swift
(?m)(?<=^NAME\n).*\n.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z3EilM/1). *Details*:

- `(?m)` - a multiline option making `^` match start of a line
- `(?<=^NAME\n)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceeded with start of a line, `NAME` and then a line feed char
- `.*\n.*` - two subsequent lines (`.*` matches zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible).

See the [Swift fiddle](https://swiftfiddle.com/i2mfvcuecvhsfm2n2lvopnepzi):

```swift
import Foundation

let line_text = "NAME\nJESUS\nLASTNAME"
if let rng = line_text.range(of: #"(?m)(?<=^NAME\n).*\n.*"#, options: .regularExpression) {
    print(String(line_text[rng]))
}
// => JESUS
//    LASTNAME
```